# prevent anyone to modify a python library

Tags: python, pypi

I am writing a open-source pypi python library that will do some calculation and then some api calls with the result of those calculation to an external service.
I want to make sure that the source code of the library was not modified when doing the api calls (I don't want anyone to modify the way I am doing the calculation). 
Is there a way of doing that?

thanks

Comment: There's a branch of formal computer science for this class of problem. Which is to say -- you can't prevent someone from modifying the library; you *might* be able to design the calculations in such a way as to make it easy to prove whether they were performed in the manner given. However, don't expect it to be easy (or simple enough to be explained in a StackOverflow answer!).

Comment: Why don't you want anyone to modify it? Isn't that what open-source facilitates?

Comment: @Charlesduffy what branch are you referring to?

Comment: @ninesalt, depends on the details. If the OP is distributing hardware and can work to tamperproof it, remote attestation is maybe the most general-purpose approach available, since one can use techniques readily available on commodity hardware to validate the chain of execution flow (baseboard, bios, bootloader, etc), with arbitrary code run should that verification pass. For something less general-purpose, I'd need to crack some textbooks to tie my fuzzy, vague memories back to specific techniques.

Comment: (I'd be rummaging around chapters fairly near to ones discussing zero-knowledge proofs, if that's any kind of useful guidance).

Comment: @PeterWood, think about use cases like http://distributed.net/ -- you're asking other people to do calculations on your behalf and return the results, and potentially be rewarded for it. Those rewards can create incentive to cheat -- to not actually do the work, but to return content that looks plausible.